# Non-Hamiltonian actions in physics

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, sg.symplectic-geometry, group-actions, hamiltonian-mechanics

I was reading the [following article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.09718.pdf) when I came across the interesting sentence

"non-Hamiltonian [symplectic group] actions also occur in physics"

I took a cursory look at [the article cited](http://www.mi-ras.ru/~snovikov/74.pdf) but nothing jumped out at me to back up the claim. Does anyone have a good example of such a thing? Ideally a classical system, if possible, as I don't have much contact with the quantum world :)

Comment: What exactly do you understand as a "Hamiltonian symplectic action"? A symplectic Lie group action which has a momentum map?

Comment: Based on your reply to Carlo Beenakker, here's an example. Consider a symplectic torus $(\mathbb{T}^2, dx\wedge dy)$, with periodic coordinates $x$ and $y$. Then the vector field $\partial/\partial x$ (and its flow) is symplectic, but not Hamiltonian. Granted, this example is a bit artificial, but it's not hard to see how similar things might come up in the wild. In general, the obstruction for a symplectic vector field to be Hamiltonian is topological, living in $H^1$ of the symplectic manifold (which needs to be non-simply connected for some obstructions to exist).

Comment: Clearly, if you have a manifold where the symplectic structure is exact (eg a cotangent bundle $(T^*L, d\lambda)$), and if $X$ is a symplectic vector field leaving $\lambda$ invariant, then $ H_X = \lambda(X) $ is a Hamiltonian function, because $dH_X = d\iota_X \lambda = L_X \lambda - \iota_X d\lambda = - \iota_X \omega$.

If $G$ is a compact Lie group acting, average first $\lambda$ over $G$ to obtain an invariant primitive for $\omega$ so that such an action is always Hamiltonian.

You will either need to consider actions of non-compact groups or symplectic manifolds that are non-exact.

Answer (score 4):

The master thesis [Nonholonomic Dynamical Systems](https://mro.massey.ac.nz/handle/10179/12894) by Brett Ryland contains several examples of non-Hamiltonian systems from classical physics: the dynamics of a laser and the evolution of a gas flame (page 14), the rattleback (page 29).

Comment: Dear Carlo, thank you for your answer, but this is not quite what I am looking for. As far as I understand, these systems are also non-symplectic (of which there are, of course, a great number). I am interested specifically in the applications of non-hamiltonian *symplectic* transformations